# Hiding certain opportunity stages from partners - how?

Tags: opportunity, partner-portal, customization

I have a request from sales, to hide certain opportunity stages from our partners (using partner portal and partner portal licenses)

The idea is that the last stage that the partner will see is : PO Submitted

We than have 2 other internal stages, but we want that for the partner, these stages will be hidden.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean that the whole Opportunity should be hidden while it's in those internal stages, or that the partner should continue to see "PO Submitted" even after the internal stage has moved on?

Comment: I don't mind hiding the "next stages" or display as: "Submitted"...

Comment: Workaround - have a "sub-stage" with the next steps that you hide?

Answer (score 0):

How about visual force page to show opportunity, then in controller if stage >  'PO Submitted' tahen put it in stage this value

Comment: I need a page for the entire oppty work flow (edit/order/update..) but also, need to hide these from reports - can't see how to do that.

Comment: I don't know that good this functionality....

But they should be able to create reports or just have access to them?
If everything is page - how about creating custom picklist to display - then copy it to standard one, and about reports - in reports instead of stage picklist give them formula field based on this picklist? I know that it is work-around but it is only thing I can think right now...

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing through an inline VF page. Using the inline VF page check the user profile and if user is a partner user check for the stage value being rendered on the opportunity record. And display a custom value on a "custom stage field".  This custom field need not to be created on object. Just declare a text field in controllerextension  and populate it on page load.

And of course you would have to remove the standard stage field from the page layout for partner users.